# Console not working when navigating or starting server in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13, console.log

I have a simple `console.log('HELLO')` statement in my `src/app/page.js` file and `src/app/products/[id]/page.js` in my next.js app as follows

```
Page() {
  console.log('HELLO')
  return <div><div/>
}
```

When I start the server or navigate between the two, the console statement does not work, but when I reload the page in the search bar by clicking enter to refresh, it works

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? Next.js renders initial page loads server-side unless you specifically add `'use client'`

Comment: Yes they dont show up there either

Comment: When you navigate between pages they are probably displayed from the browsers cache and not fetched from tgd server (check the network inspector)

Answer (score 0):

From you code example you simply are missing the right syntax. Create a file at `src/app/page.js`, this will give you access to the page at the root `/` of your page. Inside the file you add this code:

```js
export default function Page() {
  console.log("Hello my root page!");
  return <div>Root Page</div>;
}
```

Please note that the log entry will not be visible in your browsers dev-tools but inside the console you have started the next dev server from, since every page is a server component by default.